# After installing livewire 3, facing invalid or unexpected token

Tags: livewire-powergrid

I installed livewire 3, powergrid livewire 5, laravel 10 and PHP 8.2 for testing powergrid livewire datatables.
While trying to run the application, I am facing the issue shown in the image.
PowerGrid livewire datatables are not at all working

[error in livewire.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laDfQ.png)

I tried to reinstall several times but no use. I need the reason why in livewire.js error is coming as it is a installed file.